# How to add a picture with extension .HEIC in LaTeX?

Tags: includegraphics

I have a picture saved as `pic.HEIC` (created by iPhone). I would like to include this picture in my LaTeX document using `\includegraphics`. However, it is difficult to do so. Is there any way to include `pic.HEIC`? Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: The (probably) best solution would be to convert the HEIC image to one of the formats directly supported by LaTeX with another tool.

Comment: Set your iPhone to export JPG instead. If you set the Camera preference Transfer to Mac or PC -> Automatic it should upload photos in JPG not HEIC.  For existing photos if you have a Mac you can open them with Preview and export them as JPG. (No ideas if you're using another OS.)

Comment: Thank you! It works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.HEIC` file type is a high efficiency file compression container. It is especially useful on mobile devices where space is at a premium, which is why Apple uses it on the iPhone. None of the TeX engines can deal with this type directly, so you need to convert the files to JPG or some other format that they can deal with.

On the iPhone, you can set Camera Preferences -> Transfer to Mac or PC -> Automatic and it should upload photos in JPG not HEIC. For existing photos if you have a Mac you can open them with Preview and export them as JPG. For other OSes I'm sure there are converters available.